# Can I have a member field that admins use but the member can't see?

Tags: members

I have a situation where an admin wants to keep internal notes on members, but doesn't want the members to see their notes. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up modifying line 96 of /www/bbb/system/ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/View/_shared/form/fieldset.php to only display field, "Admin Comments," to a user if they were logged in the Super Admins group.

```
<div class="field-control <?php if ($setting['title'] == "Admin Comments" && ee()->session->userdata('group_id') !== 1) echo ' hidden ' ?> ">
```